# Output a alt value of an image field

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

In my Drupal 7 site, I have an image field called field_photos where users can upload an unlimited number of images, plus an alt description for each one.

I would like to print the alt description as caption for the image. How can I do this?

I know that I have to use my tpl.php file, but I am note sure which variable to use represent the alt value of an image field (especially when a field can have an unlimited number of values).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able override [theme_image_formatter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--image--image.field.inc/function/theme_image_formatter/7) which is called in [image_field_formatter_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--image--image.field.inc/function/image_field_formatter_view/7).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Do I do the override in template.php or node.tpl.php. Also, do you have an example of how to over ridden code would look?  Thanks!

Comment: Read here: http://drupal.org/theme-guide/6-7 and http://drupal.org/node/341628. In short, copy that theme function to your template.php, replace "theme_" with "yourtheme_" and then adjust/extend it in any way you want.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use or edit any .tpl.php file. You can access the alt or the title text of the image by doing the following:

1. Add another field to your View, your node's image field (yes, again)
2. Ignore the label and display options and go to the fieldset: *Multiple Field Settings* and uncheck the option: *Display all values in the same row*
3. Next, scroll down to the fieldset: *Rewrite Results* and then click *Rewrite the output of this field*. Check the Replacement Patterns below and you should see tokens for both alt and title. Use whichever is appropriate.

Works for me!

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://www.drupal.org/project/image_caption_formatter to display the title text of the image as a caption.